# Angularjs - Throw error with stack trace

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to throw exceptions and trace its path.

The only path i'm currently getting is that of angular's source code itself

But I want to trace my code it's path

Screenshot:
[image: Commandline screenshot]

Comment: That means that your code is called by angular. Which is expected, since it seems to be called as a result of a user event. Where is your code. Why do you think the stack trace should be different? What do you think it should be?

Comment: @JBNizet I know this is angular its default stack trace. I don't think it should be different, I want it different. I want to see the stack trace of my code.

Comment: Do you understand what a stack trace is? Can you explain it?

Comment: Yes. I also know there are different ways to throw an exception. 'throw new Error("message")' helpen me allot. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/JnDjMYR.png